# Running Django in Hy

Tags: django, hy

I'm writing a Django webserver using Hy, a Lisp dialect that compiles into Python ast. I have been able to write everything in Hy except for specific `.py` files that Django looks up automatically.

- `myproject/settings.py`
- `myproject/urls.py`
- `app/management/commands/my_management_command.py`

I would like to write the above files in Hy too, instead of Python.

I can work around this limitation by using these `.py` files to import `.hy` files, but I'd prefer a more elegant solution. Is there a way I can get Django to look for `.hy` files instead of these `.py` files?

Edit: corrected "bytecode" to "ast".

Comment: Technically, Hy compiles to Python [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), and then _Python_ compiles that to bytecode. That's why Hy also runs on PyPy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do normally recommend using `.py` files to import `.hy` files for this kind of thing. But Django is open source, so it would certainly be possible to patch your local install, if necessary.

Django finds `settings.py` using the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable and then imports it via `importlib`. In theory, this will work on Hy modules, provided Hy is imported first. So the trick would be to put an `import hy` statement in somewhere before that happens. There are several ways to start up Django, like `django-admin`, `manage.py`, `python -m django`. The `import hy` statement has to happen before any of these try to import a Hy module. If you just put it in `manage.py`, I think the others still wouldn't work.

You could probably create a command-line Hy script that imports Hy and then imports `manage.py`, or whatever, and runs it with its `argv`.